# Which component has been damaged?

Tags: pcb, identification, components

[image: the burnt out component is the same as the 4345 seen to the right]

I am an amateur playing around with the control board of my recently deceased dishwasher. Can anybody tell me what component burnt out? I believe it is the same as the one labeled 4345 on the same picture.

And don't worry, I will buy a new dishwasher.

Comment: Questions about the repair of devices where design-level understanding of the circuit is not available are not on topic here.  As a general point, it is quite common that the failed component like this is typically not the *original* point of failure unless the design itself is mistaken, rather something else will have gone wrong, and killed the visibly damaged component as a result.  The exceptions tend to be when a design uses a component that doesn't have enough safety margin to handle conditions it may actually see, or skips components intended to protect others.

Answer (score 1):

These components are clearly damaged. The three terminal SOT (probably sot-23 or the like) is a transistor. The code is not readable. The burned out resistor probably had code 681 (like the other one next to it, if so it would be a 680 ohm resistor.

[image]